# Oracle NVL wild card search

Tags: oracle, nvl

I have a search page where for null values I use NVL for null conditions. But for one field I have to do a wildcard search. Is nvl possible with wildcard search eg. NVL(null,%name%)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NVL in this case only as "subfunction"
If you want get also null-s results do it like this:

```
SELECT anything 
  FROM your_table 
 WHERE NVL(column_can_be_null, 'substring_you_search_for')
       LIKE '%substring_you_search_for%'
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from your_table 
where column_name like NVL('%name%',column_name)